# Mvc 5 return file mimetype does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, mime-types

What I want to achieve is returning file from my specified folder with the correct file type and specified the name. My action returns the file as it should but content type does not set. I want it to be specified as dynamically from my document path. On debug mode, I can see the file's extension set to the contentType argument.

```
public async Task<FileResult> Download(int? id, string refId, int? categoryId = null)
    {

        var document = await _documentService.GetDocument( Id = id.Value );
        if (document == null || document.RefId.ToString() != refId)
        {
            throw new Exception("NotFound");
        }

      var directory = await _categoryService.GetCategory(Session.UserId.Value, categoryId);
        var archive = Server.MapPath(directory + "/" + document.FileName);

        var contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(document.FileName);



        return File(archive, contentType, document.PureFileName);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have added file extension to the end of document.PureFileName argument and now it's working as expected.